# Cannot find symbol?

Tags: java

When I try to compile my code I am getting the error:

> 1 error found:
>
> File: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\engr
>   103\cpu.java  [line: 13]
>
> Error: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\engr
>   103\cpu.java:13: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : class BufferReader
>
> location: class cpu

I've been trying to fix this for a while now, but it's been a while since I used Java, and I have no idea what to do.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



 class cpu{
  public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
  {
    Runtime r =Runtime.getRuntime();

      String f,temp,res="";
      int i=0,j=0;
      f="sensors";
      Process p=r.exec(f);
      BufferedReader pin=new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while((temp=pin.readLine())!=null)
      {
        System.out.println(temp);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 6):

You misspelled 'BufferedReader' as 'BufferReader' on line 13.

```
BufferedReader pin = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Needs to be...

```
BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```